# Move form without border through a panel

Tags: c#, forms, mousemove

I been searching around for a solution for my problem but for now I wasn't able to get any sucessfull code for what I want to do. So, I have a form without border that is filled with 2 custom panels, so there is no way to the user click on the frame, thinking in that, I implement a code that when user click on a panel, this will call a function on my form that recive by parameter the event of the mouse.
This is the code of my Panel (note that both of my panels in the frame are the same class, it's just 2 diferent instances)

```
 public class MyPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel{

                       (...)

     private void MyPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         BarraSms.getInstance().mouseDown(e);
     }

     private void MyPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         BarraSms.getInstance().mouseMove(e);
     }

}
```

And this is the code of my form:

```
 public partial class BarraSms : Form
{
  private Point mousePoint;

             (...)

   public void mouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {

        mousePoint = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);

    }

    public void mouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point mousePos = Control.MousePosition;
            mousePos.Offset(mousePoint .X, mousePoint .Y);
            this.Location = mousePos;
        }

    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing?
Thank you in advance for the help.

The working code (update), problem solved by: x4rf41

The **MyPanel Class** :

```
MouseMove += MyPanel_MouseMove; // added in class constructer
```

the **BarraSms class (Form)**

```
public partial class BarraSms : Form
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;


    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture(); 

     public void mouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(HT_CAPTION), IntPtr.Zero);
            Point loc = this.Location;

            writeCoordToBin(loc.X, loc.Y);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is much better solution for that using the windows api function.
The way you use it, you will have a problem when you move the form very fast and the mouse goes out of the panel. I had the exact same problem.

try this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and in your Form class

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();        

public void mouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      ReleaseCapture();
      SendMessage(this.Handle,  WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(HT_CAPTION), IntPtr.Zero);
   }
}
```

no need for a mouseDown event for this

Comment: then you are doing something wrong that cant be seen in the code you posted. any errors? i use that exactly like that with a borderless form and panel, works without a problem

Comment: And you are clicking in the form or the panel? i got no errors or warnings

Comment: clicking in the panel. are you sure the event is triggered?

Comment: I notice one thing, I added  **MessageBox.Show("test");** to MyPanel_MouseMove event but it isnt showing the message, should be something wrong with my panel?

Comment: I also added a message for the move and for the methods called in my form

Comment: have you assigned the mouse event? `MouseMove += MyPanel_MouseMove;` in the `MyPanel` Class? Btw. it would be better to assign the event in the form itself, the instance call is kinda unnecessary

Comment: I just use the events on the properties of MYPanel class (from the design) the panel is made by code, so it dont have any design, there may be any function i should put on?

Comment: and this is the way i would do it, using the panel events inside the form: http://pastebin.com/YAkvfw4g you can do that with the designer of course just make sure the event is called

Comment: Thank you, that worked now, seams that i shouldn't be using the windows event and use the **MouseMove += MyPanel_MouseMove;** (didn't know that we could do that)... Thank you a lot :)

Comment: thats exactly what the designer does in the Form.designer.cs partial class. it should work too if you use the designer properly

Comment: Yes, when I remove the events I had to go remove that in some constructer, but it's weird it didn't work with the windows events... Thank you once more :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void mouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Point currentPos = Location;
        currentPos.Offset(e.X + mousePoint.X, e.Y + mousePoint.Y);
        this.Location = currentPos;
    }
    //Or simply use Location.Offset(e.X + mousePoint.X, e.Y + mousePoint.Y);
}
```

You have to use `Location` (the current location of the form), not the `Control.MousePosition` which is the location of mouse on screen.

**UPDATE**: Looks like you don't even know how to register event handlers, try modifying your panel class like this:

```
public class MyPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel{
  //(...)
 protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnMouseDown(e);
     BarraSms.getInstance().mouseDown(e);
 }

 protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnMouseMove(e);
     BarraSms.getInstance().mouseMove(e);
 }

}
```

Comment: @JoãoSilva it's strange indeed, are you sure you copied exactly my code?

Comment: Yes I did, but the answer as on x4rf41 answer and comments, I had to create the event in step of using the windows events...

Comment: @JoãoSilva from your comment, I'm pretty sure that you have not attached your handlers correctly, you can try my updated code (with some important modification to your `MyPanel` class).

Comment: I updated my code, it's working now, the problem, and i dont know why, was in the event of the mouse. I had to create manually the event because the windows event wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your private methods in MyPanel cannot be called by the framework. You need to declare them as follows:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = this.Parent as BarraSms;
    parent.mouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = this.Parent as BarraSms;
    parent.mouseMove(e);
}
```

Comment: That give me an error when I click in the panel, that may be because my panel is a static readonly class? **private static readonly BarraSms instance = new BarraSms();**

Comment: Sorry. I assumed the panels were child controls of the form. If the panel's parent is anything other than your form then `parent.mouseDown(e)` clearly won't work.

Comment: No problem, if you want to see the answer x4rf41 answer the question, the problem was on the windows events, i guess

Comment: `var form = this.FindForm() as BarraSms;`
`form.mouseMove(e);`