# Move windows form from a picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a windows form without any border.
So i added a picture box and i want the whole form to be moved when that picture box is clicked.

```
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
    int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    private void header_image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        } 
    }
```

That is the code which i am using atm.But my problem is that if i move cursor very fast it is not sticked on the picture box.

I tried to find a solution but nothing came up.
I used some info from those 2 links:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289303/move-form-without-border-through-a-panel)

[link 2](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/124165-c%23-moving-border-less-form/)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the whole code of my form

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
    int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    private void header_image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. What is the function of the Picturebox?? Have you the same code also for the Form1_MouseDown ? Any other mouse events coded?

Comment: the fucntion is MouseDown. and is only for picturebox.And no there are no other mouse events coded.
I just want to move the whole form only from the header_image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this code:

```js
 private bool draging = false;
        private Point pointClicked;
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (draging)
            {
                Point pointMoveTo;
                pointMoveTo = this.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                pointMoveTo.Offset(-pointClicked.X, -pointClicked.Y);
                this.Location = pointMoveTo;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                draging = true;
                pointClicked = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
            else
            {
                draging = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            draging = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MouseMove()` event instead of `MouseDown()`:

```
    private void header_image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
```